# How to get ECS service to do a force redeploy?

Tags: terraform

I have a docker image in ECR which I update frequently. I would like ECS to do a force deploy in order to get the service to pick up the latest version of the image.

The service is checked into terraform so I would rather have terraform do the heavy lifting for me instead of writing a script to force redeploy.

How can I leverage terraform to force ECS service redeploy?

Comment: Do you use the same tag or are you updating the tag and thus task definition? Can you share your Terraform code that creates the task definition and service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I found that works best is to **taint the task definition**.

```
terraform taint -module=mysandbox aws_ecs_task_definition.sandbox
terraform apply

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  ~ module.mysandbox.aws_ecs_service.sandbox
      task_definition:       "some-old-arn" => "${aws_ecs_task_definition.sandbox.arn}"

-/+ module.mysandbox.aws_ecs_task_definition.sandbox (tainted) (new resource required)
      ...
      revision:              "3" => <computed>
```

As you can see the task definition in the ecs_service is updated to the new  task definition which has an incremented revision number.